# How to fetch caller's mobile operator in Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, web-applications

I am designing a mobile application. However, I am stuck with a situation. This app needs caller's location as well as mobile operator.

However, as you know that people change mobile operators for the same number. Could you please suggest any method by which we can track current mobile operators. Is there any custom API for this?

Comment: why here is the iOS tag whereas you set android in the title?

Comment: I want to build this app on both platform however for now, I am developing it for Android.

Answer (score 1):

```
 TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,. However, are you sure that this API will provide correct info even after caller switches the number to some other operator.?

Comment: Yes I changed My Operator Last Week And It shows My Current Operator